# How to add a class to a .jar library?

Tags: java, jar

I need to add a class to a .jar library but I can't figure out how to do it.
I have a library named `netty-3.1.5.GA.jar` but for some reason its missing a class I need 
(`HttpTunnelClientChannelFactory.java`).

I have found that class on a repository but not as part of the library. So how can I 'inject' it? The class I need to add is using other classes that exist in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `jar` tool to update the jar file: you will need to manually create the appropriate package directory though. Try this:

```
jar uf netty-3.1.5.GA.jar HttpTunnelClientChannelFactory.class
```

will add it to the root package. If you need it to be set up in a package directory you should create the directory structure and then add the file with a path.

EDIT: that should be `.class`, not `.java`.

Comment: (Of course, adding a Java file to a jar isn't particularly helpful ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add it to the jar, you need to add it to the classpath of whatever it is you're running.

Comment: I know thats an option but is there a way to add it to the library?

Comment: Why would you want to? But sure: unjar the jar, copy the class file into the appropriate directory, jar it back up again.

Comment: Hm ok ill see what i can do ... the thing is there is something like few hundreds of classes in there ,so i asked here in case someone knew some tricky way to do that. Thanks tho

Comment: Why does the number of classes in the jar file matter?

Comment: You don't have to extract the jar. With Winrar/7Zip or some other zip program, you can open it and add the file into the proper package too.

Comment: Ok i didnt know that. My pc can only run it/extract it . Thanks ill check that

Comment: Yep, Yasin's correct, you could do that too. But the whole question baffles me somewhat.